# Angularjs is not giving data from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, model-view-controller, ng-controller

I am new to AngularJS.

I am following [MEAN Stack Intro: Build an end-to-end application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEE7DY2AYvI)

I have simple html file to test [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs).

*index.html*

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Stack POC</title>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="app/scripts/controllers/user_controller.js"></script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body ng-app="userListApp">
        <div ng-controller="userListController">
            <h1>No of users {{userCounts}}</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*app/scripts/controllers/user_controller.js*

```
angular.module('userListApp', []).controller('userListController', function($scope){ 
                $scope.userCounts = 10;
                });
```

But when I try to run this, its not giving.

**No of users {{ userCounts }}**

Instead of `10` in count.

I am using [gulp](/questions/tagged/gulp) and [gulp-connect](/questions/tagged/gulp-connect) to run dev server.

*gulpfile.js*

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('serve', function() {
    connect.server({
        root: '.',
        port: 8888
    }); 
}); 

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "poc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-connect": "^3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Using [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) 45.0.2 to view this page.

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle with your controller logic?

Comment: updated question with package file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are just providing a single function and don't provide a full controller.

Try something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Stack POC</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
        angular.module('userListApp', []).controller('userListController', function($scope){
            $scope.userCounts = 10;
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="userListApp">
        <div ng-controller="userListController">
            <h1>No of users {{ userCounts }}</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You need a module (I named it `userListApp` in your example) which is created by the angular.module() function. The second parameter would be the dependencies (empty array means none). On that module you can build up a controller. You have to pass `$scope` as an argument to the controller function to use it in your example. In the controller you could assign the referred variable like you tried it in the previous function.

Comment: If i move script to js file and include that js in `head` section, then it stop working :(. Do you have any idea why it is like so ?

Comment: It should still work. The only important thing is to add the new script reference below the angular import. Is there an error message in the console or something?

Comment: I updated my question, there is not error in console

Comment: There is no reference to angular anymore (in your updated html file). Insert your angular script tag above the other script tag: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>`

Comment: And I don't mean the console which you use for your gulp build, I mean the web console. It's depending on your bowser but in most cases you can open the console by pressing the `f12` key.

Answer (score 1):

You are not instantiating AngularJS app anywhere in your script. You need to provide the application name as an argument to `ng-app` in `body` tag and modify the `script` as well.

The function `userListController` needs to be attached to AngularJS controller using `app.controller`.

Please refer the following working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/akonchady/7kfv4ssk/1/